# Getting "failed to issue sandbox extension for file ( .MP4 )" error

Tags: ios, swift

I need your help to resolve the below error.

Actually, when I am uploading a **.MP4** file from the **XCODE Simulator** then files are uploading perfectly but when I am uploading via **iPhone** it's not transferring the file to the **S3 bucket**. I checked few posts and found the issue is producing due to the latest version of **iOS 14.4.2** but nothing 100% proved.

So is anyone can help me to resolve this issue, please?

```
failed to issue sandbox extension for file file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/102APPLE/IMG_2255.MP4, errno = 1
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: yes, we stored that under the temp path and then send it to the S3 bucket.